# How do I get OpenGL/GLUT working with Eclipse IDE (cocoa 64 bit) using C++ and on Snow Leopard

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl, osx-snow-leopard

This seems like it should be strait forward, but a lot of the information I'm finding it pre-snow leopard, deals with cocoa and carbon, or the XCode IDE.  None of which helps me with my problem at hand.

I simply want to compile, and run openGL using C++ without becoming dependent on the Mac environment since I will most likely need to get my code running on a linux box.  Minor changes may be unavoidable though...

I've found the header files and can include them but I'm having trouble with the linking, compiling, and executing within Eclipse.

Thanks.

Comment: Same problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068693/opengl-and-glut-in-eclipse-on-os-x

Comment: Hmm, very similar.  What is the proper way to resolve this?

Comment: I'll answer this with a link to the other similar question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see my answer at [OpenGL and GLUT in Eclipse on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068693/opengl-and-glut-in-eclipse-on-os-x)