# Run opengl and glut on Mac C++ Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl, glut, macos

I am working with Mac OS X 10.5 and Eclipse 32 bit. I would like to run the simple graphics program by making the use of either GLUT or OpenGL. I had followed the instruction provided [OpenGL and GLUT in Eclipse on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068693/opengl-and-glut-in-eclipse-on-os-x) but still I am unable to run the program listed in the derick post of [OpenGL and GLUT in Eclipse on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068693/opengl-and-glut-in-eclipse-on-os-x/2084228#2084228)
I also don't know exactly about my OS whether it is 64 bit or 32 bit.

Comment: Mac 32 or 64 bit: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3696

Comment: What error messages do you get?

Comment: GLUT and OpenGL are very separate things. GLUT is a simple framework, intended for small test programs using OpenGL. OpenGL is a drawing API that's not tied to any framework (well in MacOS X it's tied to the OpenGL Cocoa Framework, but that's something different).

Answer (score 1):

Here are the settings that work for me. I am currently working in windows, but these settings have been tested in Mac OS X and they work. That extra bit about GLEW is optional, and not normally included in Mac OS X. If you want to use GLEW, you have to compile GLEW for Mac OS X yourself.

[image: Misc Linker Settings]

[image: GCC C++ Include Settings]

[image: Linker Library Settings]