# Setting up OpenGL in Eclipse (OSX)

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, opengl

I am trying to set up OpenGL on Eclipse C++. I have followed the steps described in the answer of [1], but, when I do that it appears the following:

```
Building target: opengltest
Invoking: MacOS X C++ Linker
g++ -L/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/X11/lib -L/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL -framework Cocoa  -arch i686 -o "opengltest"  ./main.o   -lgl -lglu -lglut
ld: library not found for -lglut
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [opengltest] Error 1
```

I have also changed the include line to:

```
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
```

Why is this error appearing?

[1] [OpenGL and GLUT in Eclipse on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068693/opengl-and-glut-in-eclipse-on-os-x?rq=1)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068693/opengl-and-glut-in-eclipse-on-os-x?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You followed a tutorial aimed at Linux/BSD developers. In MacOS X you neither use the X11 server not link directly to the OpenGL interface libraries. In MacOS you merely add the OpenGL framework (add `-framework OpenGL` to the compiler command options). I'm not an active Eclipse user, but I'm pretty sure, it recognized MacOS X frameworks and you can just add the OpenGL framework to it.

GLUT is not part of OpenGL it's an independent library, but it used to be part of the MacOS X OpenGL framework for some time. Recently it was moved into a separate framework.

To add further speed bumps, Apple decided, that they'd put the OpenGL header files not into the canonical place `GL/…`, but into `OpenGL/…` so that you'll have to litter your program source text with `#ifdef` preprocessor statements

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#else
#include <GL/gl.h>
#endif
```